# Parsing expressions from Token Stream

Tags: parsing, expression

I'm trying to parse expressions for a simple scripting language, but I'm confused. Right now, only numbers and string literals can be parsed as an expression:

```
int x = 5;
double y = 3.4;
str t = "this is a string";
```

However, I am confused on parsing more complex expressions:

```
int a = 5 + 9;
int x = (5 + a) - (a ^ 2);
```

I'm thinking I would implement it like:

```
do {
    // no clue what I would do here?        

    if (current token is a semi colon) break;
}
while (true);
```

Any help would be great, I have no clue where to start. Thanks.

EDIT: 
My parser is a Recursive Descent Parser

My expression "class" is as follows:

```
typedef struct s_Expression {
    char type;
    Token *value;

    struct s_Expression *leftHand;
    char operand;
    struct s_Expression *rightHand;
} ExpressionNode;
```

Someone mentioned that a Recursive Descent Parser is capable of parsing expressions without doing infix, to postfix. Preferably, I would like an Expression like this:

For example this:

```
int x = (5 + 5) - (a / b);
```

Would be parsed into this:
Note: this isn't valid C, this is just some pseudo ish code to get my point across simply :)

```
ExpressionNode lh;
lh.leftHand = new ExpressionNode(5);
lh.operand = '+'
lh.rightHand = new ExpressionNode(5);

ExpressionNode rh;
rh.leftHand = new ExpressionNode(a);
rh.operand = '/';
rh.rightHand = new ExpressionNode(b);

ExpressionNode res;
res.leftHand = lh;
res.operand = '-';
res.rightHand = rh;
```

I asked the question pretty late at night, so sorry if I wasn't clear and that I completely forgot what my original goal was.

Comment: Use the well known rules of expression grammar

Comment: What do you expect the output of `int a = 5 + 9;` to be? 14? Machine code that performs the addition? RPN? An [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)? The programs for all those things are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I ended up using is [Operator precedence parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser).

```
parse_expression_1 (lhs, min_precedence)
    lookahead := peek next token
    while lookahead is a binary operator whose precedence is >= min_precedence
        op := lookahead
        advance to next token
        rhs := parse_primary ()
        lookahead := peek next token
        while lookahead is a binary operator whose precedence is greater
                 than op's, or a right-associative operator
                 whose precedence is equal to op's
            rhs := parse_expression_1 (rhs, lookahead's precedence)
            lookahead := peek next token
        lhs := the result of applying op with operands lhs and rhs
    return lhs
```

Comment: As long as your expressions don't include unary operators (e.g., `a=!b`) you should be fine with this. Likewise, the ternary operator `?:`, if existent in your expressions, won't parse with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods to do this. One I've used in the past is to read the input string (that is, the programming language code) and convert expressions from infix to reverse-polish notation. Here's a really good post about doing just that:

http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/

Note that `=` is an operator also, so your parsing should really include the whole file of code, and not just certain expressions.

Once in reverse-polish, expressions are super-easy to evaluate. You just pop the stack, storing operands as you go, until you hit an operator. Pop as many operands from the stack as required by the operator and perform your operation.

Comment: This is perfect, I've seen the shunting yard algorithm before and never quite understood it. Your last paragraph hits the nail on the head, thanks!

Comment: Note my comment in the newly-edited third paragraph about `=`.

Comment: Can you expand on that part please? I don't quite understand.

Comment: E.g., `x=(2*y)+a^2` in RPN would be `x,2,y,*,a,2,^,+,=`.

Comment: I don't get it; a Recursive Descent parser is perfectly able to handle expression evaluation without using a shunting yard, and can evaluate the expression or output RPN if that is what you are after.

Comment: @DourHighArch, Sure, an RD parser will work, too. As I said, there are multiple methods to do this. I just posted one. Perhaps you could post something about an RD parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a recursive descent parser, implementing a shunting yard is a lot of unnecessary work because recursive descent is perfectly capable of evaluating expressions or outputting RPN by itself.

You haven't told us anything about your programming language, your `Token` structs, or even what you are trying to achieve, so it is really hard to give you sample code. Take a look at Eric White's [implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/07/30/building-a-simple-recursive-descent-parser.aspx) of a recursive descent parser in C#. If you provide more details we will be able to help more.

Comment: Sorry, I just woke up and realised how stupid I was haha. I've updated my question :)